# Android animation - Initial state of view

Tags: android, animation, android-view

I've got an `Animation` that results in a view sliding out of the screen to the right, this is working as expected with the following code:

```
Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,  +1.0f,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,   0.0f
        );
outtoRight.setDuration(500);
outtoRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
outtoRight.setFillAfter(true);
```

This means that the view to which I apply this animation will slide beautifully out of the screen. I have an opposite for sliding in of course. But my question is, how can I have the view out of the screen so I can slide it in without applying this animation to it at least once?

I've played with negative margins and such, but I cant seem to find the right properties for my view to be out of the screen on launch.

Just to clarify, I can hide it perfectly on start with another animation, but I can see it going away, even if its for a fraction of a second. There must be a way for it to just not be there at the beginning and allow me to slide it in afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert on animations but I'll give it a shot :)

This is the animation I am using, it slides a view in from  the right side

**EnterByRight.xml**

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
      android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="400"/>
   </set>
```

In my case, i am animating a TableLayout defined in xml. When i want it to slide in :

```
Animation animationEnterByRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animationentrancebyright);
tableLayout.startAnimation(animationEnterByRight);
```

and it comes from out of the screen, I don't need to position it outside first, the animation takes care of that for me. This works fine if you want to animate your view as soon as it's loaded.

If you need to keep your view "invisble" for a period of time, and then display the animation I can't think about any solution other than View.Visible and View.Gone. But I didn't understand why is that a problem?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution (given the really low popularity of this question) can be the one I'm currently using, even though I don't like it at all. I've made the view to have a visibility of `View.GONE` and apply the animation that makes it go away to the right.

Then, the first time (I control it's the first time with a tag on the view) I set the visibility to `View.VISIBLE` and apply the animation to slide in. This works as expected without glitches and jumps, but I'm still concerned about the implications of adding an animation to a lot of elements at once performance related.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your own answer is not bad at all. The only thing I would change is not setting you view viability to `GONE` but creating and adding it manually using `addChild()`.

Do it in separated thread, add the animation in separated thread, and only call `addChild()` on the main thread.

In generally, you should do the init process on separated threads, so the UI thread will not be effected, and if it takes more then 0.4 seconds you should start playing a loading animation for minimum 0.5 seconds. This is the best UI practice I can tell you, I did it in my app and it's work great!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `outtoRight.setFillBefore(false);` ?

Comment: Tried it, thing is that I'd need a third animation just to place it out of the screen to start with, that seems a little bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an PreDrawListner() to set the view's position out of the screen before it draws, and then run a slide-in animation for it.

```
yourview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            yourview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            yourview.setTranslationX(something that will take it out of the screen, depends on padding);
            yourview.runIntroAnimation();
            return false;
       }
};
```